# Make macro used in section title behave differently in toc

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I am writing lecture notes for a course and use a macro to insert week numbers into section titles as indicated:

[image: example of used macro in section title]

The latex code would be

```
\subsection{Finite fields\weektag}
```

The week number is stored in a counter

```
\newcounter{weekcounter}
```

I would now like either or both of the following two behaviors in the table of content:

```
Contents
...
3.3 Topic before
3.4 Week 7: Finite fields
3.5 Topic after
...
```

or that actually every subsection (so not only those where the macro is used in the section title) gets the week number attached

```
Contents
...
3.3 Week 6: Topic before
3.4 Week 7: Finite fields
3.5 Week 7: Topic after
...
```

where the subsection title lines read

```
\subsection{Topic before}
...
\subsection{Finite fields\weektag}
...
\subsection{Topic after}
```

So my first question is

**How can I determine inside the macro whether I am in the table of contents or in the body of the text to alter the macro's behavior depending on the situation?**

and my second question is

**How can I use the above counter to generally write something into all subsection table of content entries?**

Many thanks!

An MWE that I currently have is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcounter{weekcounter}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\weektag}{
  \stepcounter{weekcounter}
  \todo[size=\tiny,color=red!10]{\hfil\textbf{week \theweekcounter}\hfil}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}

some text

\section[Section 2]{\weektag Section 2}

some text

\section{Section 3}

some text

\end{document}
```

producing

[image: MWE]

The table of contents there should now be either looking like

[image: MWE option 1]

or like

[image: MEW option 2]

Comment: sorry, but no one can help you here unless you provide a full but minimal example that others an copy and test as is. You have not even shown that the definition of `\weektag` is!

Comment: @daleif: That's right, I will provide a mwe, but for the matter of the question, it seems completely irrelevant what ``\weektag`` does. The questions are both completely generic without a reference to any concrete situation. (But I might obviously be wrong, for example the document class ``paper`` might be important to know.) I'll add one.

Comment: semiautomatic: `\subsection[\weektag Finite fields]{Finite fields\weektag}` ...

Comment: You need clarify your question. It is not clear what you like to achieve. Proposed solution works for section, subsection,. sunsub sections ... etc

Comment: I added an MWE and hope it becomes clearer now.

Comment: @Zarko: Your proposed solution messes with the counter increment but I might find a workaround for that. I nonetheless would prefer a nice and clear and easily handable solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a different command for the job.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcounter{weekcounter}
% \weektag might print the tag in the right margin
\DeclareRobustCommand{\weektag}{%
  \todo[size=\tiny,color=red!10]{\hfil\textbf{week \theweekcounter}\hfil}%
}
% the main command wraps \section
\newcommand{\lecture}[1]{%
  \section[\protect\printweek #1]{#1\perhapschangeweek}%
}
% conditionally print the tag
\newcommand{\perhapschangeweek}{%
  % the current value of week
  \edef\thisweek{\theweekcounter}%
  % compare with the previously set value; if different, print the tag
  \ifx\thisweek\currentweek\else\weektag\fi
  % set the current week value
  \global\let\currentweek\thisweek
}
% change week: step the counter and do the same in the toc
\newcommand{\newweek}{%
  \stepcounter{weekcounter}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\stepcounter{weekcounter}}%
}
% a conditional to see whether we're in the toc
\newif\ifintoc
% \printweek does nothing outside of the tok
\newcommand{\printweek}{\ifintoc Week \theweekcounter: \fi}
% before starting \tableofcontents set the conditional to true
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/before}{\intoctrue}
% after \tableofcontents set the conditional to false and reset weekcounter
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{\intocfalse\setcounter{weekcounter}{0}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\lecture{Section 1}

some text

\newweek

\lecture{Section 2}

some text

\lecture{Section 3}

some text

\newweek

\lecture{Section 4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to start weeks from 1: change

```
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{\intocfalse\setcounter{weekcounter}{0}}
```

into

```
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{\intocfalse\setcounter{weekcounter}{0}\newweek}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I determine inside the macro whether I am in the table of contents or in the body of the text to alter the macro's behavior depending on the situation?

Probably checking the definition of `\protect` is sufficient.

`\texorpdfstring` can be used for detecting whether TeX is in the situation of creating a pdf-string, e.g., a bookmark, which does not show up within a page of the document but is displayed separately.

> How can I use the above counter to generally write something into all subsection table of content entries?

If you look at the .toc-file, you find entries `\contentsline{subsection}...`.

Probably you can introduce an `\if..`-switch, which usually is false, and patch `\contentsline` so that to its 2nd argument, which denotes the text phrase of the entry of the table of contents, the value of the week-counter etc is prepended in case the switch is "true".

If you do this you still need a mechanism for transporting values of the week-counter and setting the `\if..`-switch into the toc-file. The following example does this via `\addtocontents`.

`\weektagstepped` is used for incrementing `weekcounter` and displaying the week-tag and adding the week to the table of contents and the bookmarks (if hyperref is loaded).

`\weektag` is used for displaying the week-tag (without incrementing the `weektag`-counter)  adding the week to the table of contents and the bookmarks (if hyperref is loaded).

`\weektoc` is used for adding the week to the table of contents and the bookmarks (if hyperref is loaded). (No displaying of the week-tag and no incrementing the `weektag`-counter.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{nameref}

\newcounter{weekcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\weekcountervalue{}%
\newcommand\pdfweeknum{}%
%-------- Can't do \begin{NoHyper}...\end{NoHyper} as that
%         yields unknown-destination-errors with the 
%         `\todo`-command. It would also break the list of todo notes -------
\newcommand\saved@currentHref{}%
\newcommand\saved@currentlabelname{}%
\newcommand\saved@currentlabel{}%
\newcommand\savecurrentref{%
  \global\let\saved@currentHref\@currentHref
  \global\let\saved@currentlabelname\@currentlabelname
  \global\let\saved@currentlabel\@currentlabel
}%
\newcommand\restorecurrentref{%
  \global\let\@currentHref\saved@currentHref
  \global\let\@currentlabelname\saved@currentlabelname
  \global\let\@currentlabel\saved@currentlabel
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% This is used to prepend "Week \theweekcounter: " to pdf-bookmarks:
%   Probably some of the things should not be done in terms of global
%   but only in the group-level where the sectioning-command occurs:
\newcommand\savedpdfstringdefPostHook{}%
\newcommand\patchpdfstringdefposthook{%
  \@ifundefined{pdfstringdef}{}{%
    \pdfstringdef\pdfweeknum{Week \theweekcounter: }%
    \global\let\savedpdfstringdefPostHook=\pdfstringdefPostHook
    \gdef\pdfstringdefPostHook##1{%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter##1%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\pdfweeknum##1}%
       \global\let\pdfstringdefPostHook=\savedpdfstringdefPostHook
       \gdef\pdfweeknum{}%
       \pdfstringdefPostHook##1%
    }%
  }%
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\weektagstepped}{%
  \@ifundefined{texorpdfstring}{\@firstoftwo}{\texorpdfstring}%
  {%
    \ifx\protect\relax % Probably in main document, not toc or the like
       \ifx\label\@gobble\else % Probably not in \nameref
         \stepcounter{weekcounter}%
         \addtocontents{toc}{%
           \string\def\string\weekcountervalue{\theweekcounter}%
           \string\InsertWeekcountertrue
         }%
         \savecurrentref
         \todo[size=\tiny,color=red!10]{\hfil\textbf{week \theweekcounter}\hfil}%
         % Restore referencing-data. Otherwise referencing-labels
         % denote the place where \todo started drawing the line 
         % and pdf-bookmarks and cross-referencing-links won't lead
         % to scrolling to the left end of the sectioning heading -
         % wrapping \todo between \begin{NoHyper}..\end{NoHyper}
         % leads to unknown-destination-errors:
         \restorecurrentref
         \patchpdfstringdefposthook
      \fi
    \fi
  }{}%
}%
\newcommand{\weektag}{%
  \@ifundefined{texorpdfstring}{\@firstoftwo}{\texorpdfstring}%
  {%
    \ifx\protect\relax % Probably in main document, not toc or the like
       \ifx\label\@gobble\else % Probably not in \nameref
         \addtocontents{toc}{\string\InsertWeekcountertrue}%
         \savecurrentref
         \todo[size=\tiny,color=red!10]{\hfil\textbf{week \theweekcounter}\hfil}%
         % Restore referencing-data. Otherwise referencing-labels
         % denote the place where \todo started drawing the line 
         % and pdf-bookmarks and cross-referencing-links won't lead
         % to scrolling to the left end of the sectioning heading -
         % wrapping \todo between \begin{NoHyper}..\end{NoHyper}
         % leads to unknown-destination-errors:
         \restorecurrentref
         \patchpdfstringdefposthook
       \fi
    \fi
  }{}%
}%
\newcommand{\weektoc}{%
  \@ifundefined{texorpdfstring}{\@firstoftwo}{\texorpdfstring}%
  {%
    \ifx\protect\relax % Probably in main document, not toc or the like
      \ifx\label\@gobble\else % Probably not in \nameref
        \addtocontents{toc}{\string\InsertWeekcountertrue}%
        \patchpdfstringdefposthook
      \fi
    \fi
  }{}%
}%
\newif\ifInsertWeekcounter
\@ifdefinable\contentslinecopy{\let\contentslinecopy\contentsline}%
\newcommand\behindnumberline[3]{#2{#3}#1}%
\renewcommand\contentsline[2]{%
  \contentslinecopy{#1}{%
    \ifInsertWeekcounter\global\InsertWeekcounterfalse\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
    {%
      \@ifnextchar\numberline{\behindnumberline{Week \weekcountervalue: }}{Week \weekcountervalue: }%
    }%
    #2%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\verb|\ref{Firstlecturesecondweek}|: \ref{Firstlecturesecondweek}

% \noindent\verb|\nameref{Firstlecturesecondweek}|: \nameref{Firstlecturesecondweek}

\subsection{Only one lecture in the first week\weektagstepped}

some text \hfill some text  \hfill some text 

\subsection{First lecture in the second week\weektagstepped}
\label{Firstlecturesecondweek}%
\subsection{Second lecture in the 2nd week\weektag}
\subsection{Third lecture in the 2nd week\weektag}
\subsection{Fourth lecture in the 2nd week\weektoc}
\subsection{Something probably in the 2nd week}

some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Bookmarks if hyperref is loaded:

[image]

Comment: This does indeed seem to answer my first question, many thanks! I played with ``\texorpdfstring`` yesterday already a bit, but it seemed not right to use that to determine whether I am in the toc or not.